Difference in horizontal placement of 'align*' and 'aligned' environments when embedded in a 'gather*' environment
(I've updated this question to incorporate @daleif's suggestion to use \boxed statements to highlight the internal dimensions of the second row in each gather* environment`.)
This question is inspired by an issue I noticed while posting an answer to this query.
Consider the following, highly stylized code, which contains four distinct gather* environments or blocks. All four gather* blocks contain two rows. The second row in each block is encased in a \boxed statement to show its internal dimensions.

In the first block, both rows form part of a simple gather* environment. Both rows are horizontally centered -- as should be the case.

In the second block, the second line is embedded in an align* environment. The second line is no longer centered relative to either the first row or the width of the text block.

In the third and fourth blocks, the second lines are embedded in aligned environments. The third and fourth blocks differ only in the presence, or absence, of an & alignment point marker.


Clearly, the contents of the align* environment in block 2 aren't centered horizontally with respect to overall gather* environment. On page 26 of the user guide of the amsmath package, one finds the statement that an "align [environment] and most of its variants can be used inside the gather environment."
Question: Is this not also the case for nesting an align* environment inside a gather* environment?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
aaa\\
\boxed{a = b}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
aaa\\
\boxed{%
\begin{align*}
   a &= b 
\end{align*}
}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
aaa\\
\boxed{%
\begin{aligned}
   a = b  % <-- no "&" alignment point specified
\end{aligned}
}
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
aaa\\
\boxed{%
\begin{aligned}
   a &= b % <-- one "&" alignment point specified
\end{aligned}
}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


You can highlight the latter two a bit more by wrapping them in \boxed{}. The last aligned has extra space in the right. It also shows what is going on with align.

I just ran the example through TL24,23,22,21,20, they all give the same result

@daleif - Many thanks for suggesting to use \boxed statements to highlight the internal dimensions of the second rows in each of the gather* environments. I've updated my posting to incorporate your suggestion.

Uhh, try adding eq numbers, then align inside gather is correct, and \boxed will show you why

@daleif - Embedding an align environment inside the gather environment (note the absence of asterisks) does assure the desired horizontal centering. That's why I modified my main question to ask if this shouldn't also hold if an align* environment is embedded in a gather* environment.
